# JLabel.setIcon() not working properly on Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

This is my first attempt to NetBeans's gui creation tool.

I've a JLabel in which I want to display an image. This is how I'm doing

```
thumbnail = new JLabel();
thumbnail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
thumbnail.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/../blabla/../DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL.png")));
```

Now, the preview design shows me perfectly the image BUT when I run my app it is not working. There is no image at all.

The way I'm launching it (from my controller super cool class):

```
// in the controller, I need the gui has a reference to myself because msg handling
gui = New Gui(this);
gui.setVisible(true);
```

What is the difference between *NetBeans's preview code* and my initialization code (I'm assuming the code to set a image to a label is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the reason *but* it's smth related to NetBeans and using MacOs, if someone come across this situation, ImageIO is the solution.

Instead of just

```
thumbnail.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClassLoader().getResource("bla-bla")));
```

use this

```
thumbnail.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClassLoader().getResource("bla-bla")));
```